# Facebook API php - Post a news item to a facebook group

Tags: php, facebook

**strong text**I have a website that publishes articles every day.

I want to have a corresponding Facebook group that I can publish the articles to at the same time as on my site.

I have set up a similar arrangement in twitter using the api. When I publish an article to my site I it automatiaclly posts the headline and link back to twitter via the twitter API. I would like to have a similar arrangement for my facebook group.

Is it possible to have my stories forwarded to my facebook group wall?

**EDIT**

Ok, I have gotten this far, and no further:

Step 1: Get authorisation to publish to the stream

```
if ($fp = fopen('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXtype=client_cred&scope=publish_stream', 'r')) {
    $content = '';
    // keep reading until there's nothing left
    while ($line = fread($fp, 1024)) {
        $content .= $line;
    }
    $tokens = explode("access_token=",$content);

    // do something with the content here
    $auth_token = $tokens[1];
    fclose($fp);


} else {
    // echo" an error occured when trying to open the specified url";
}
```

Step 2: send my message to the stream using my authorisation code (I have chosen to use cURL):

```
 $message="This will be a post on my groups wall.";
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/my_app_id/feed";

$data = array('message' => $message, 'auth_token' => $auth_token);

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

if (empty($buffer))
{
    print "Nothing seems to have happened";
}
else
{
    print $buffer;
}
```

The code runs with no errors, but nothing gets returned and nothing gets posted to the wall

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook treats pages similar to the way they treat people, you specify a UID which is associated with the Page ID of your group. Then just use Facebook's Graph API to post to the stream, just as you would a person.

To authorize, you get Facebook API permission from an admin and request the `manage_pages` permission.

All of the information you need is contained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#impersonation.

(Ctrl+F `Page Login` for more information on authorizing to update to pages).